# run two containers from same image, same machine, different sshd ports

Tags: docker, networking

The Question:

Is it possible to have two containers running, from the same image, 
on the same host (linux) machine, but with ssh listening on two different ports,
so two (outside docker) editor sessions can talk to the two containers at the same time?
Maybe using a combination of --expose and the sshd -p flag?
I do not want to attach to ssh from an external machine (different from where the containers are running).

Should the image be built with an EXPOSE command (set to an env variable?),
or no expose command?

I know nothing about networking. 
I read several articles e.g. about the difference 
between "expose" and "publishing" and the terminology is beyond me.
Please tune the answer to a beginner (in terms of networking).

Background:

1. I am using docker to encapsulate a programming language and its libraries in a reproducable way. This is particularly important for my work, which sometimes requires revisiting an old project and exactly reproducing the previous output before making changes.
2. Specifically, the container is run like this

`sudo docker run -p 7776:22 --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/work --ipc=host imagename`

Then inside the container

`/usr/sbin/sshd -D`

Then from outside *but on the same machine* I attach the code editor/IDE, which talks to the container through sshd somehow. (Followed a tutorial, it works fine)

3. I want to be able to have several sessions open on the same machine,
   one of them running a long job, second one to do work on a different program, 
   but using the same programming environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should the image be built with an EXPOSE command (set to an env variable?), or no expose command?

The `EXPOSE` command does pretty much nothing. It's not necessary, and has no influence on the behavior of the container.

> Is it possible to have two containers running, from the same image, on the same host (linux) machine, but with ssh listening on two different ports, so two (outside docker) editor sessions can talk to the two containers at the same time?

Sure.  Just publish the ssh service on different host ports.  E.g., start one container with `-p 2221:22` and another with `-p 2222:22`. Now you have two ssh containers running, one reachable on host port `2221` and another on host port `2222`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run more than 1 container using same image.

Name them differently
Change the host port. The internal SSH port remains 22.

```
sudo docker run -p 7776:22 -name long_job --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/work --ipc=host imagename

sudo docker run -p 7777:22 -name other_job --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/work --ipc=host imagename
```

And so on.

Your external software instances should use ports 7776 and 7777 , .... to reach each container.